# display or hide row on change of session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**EDIT: I CHANGED THE php VALUE TO BUSINESS**

I was trying to change fields using a session value which comes from another page. So, I set type hidden and stored the php value collected from session. And I want when the hidden field value is equal to "Business" the field get display otherwise it remain hidden. But it not change it show full form.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="Business" onload="myFunction">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Category: " />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <table id="Other" style="display: none">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

the JS:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
if(x.value.match === "Business"){
document.getElementById("other").style.display = "block";
}
else{
document.getElementById("other").style.display = "none";
}

}
```

Comment: how you read the value from session? when it get triggered?

Comment: Not able to see your session variable in your code

Comment: You didn't even start your session

Comment: can you see echoing <?php $value; ?> to make sure there is no whitespace or case-sensitive issue?

Comment: yes everything is running fine..please consider the php value as Business

Comment: does the script work in php I wonder, because I can see asp form , IDK, are you sure its working?

Comment: check the fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ykdkgaw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Function call syntax is incorrect,

```
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="Business" onload="myFunction">
```

change to

```
 <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="Business" onload="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: you must echo your PHP value, either is not set a value on input filed.

check input field or you can try it.

```
<body>
<?php
  if($value === "Business"){
 ?>
<input type="text" name = "values" id="myInput" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" >
 <?php 
  }else{
 ?>
 <input type="hidden" name = "values" id="myInput" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" >
 <?php }?>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the table tag inside a div like,

```
<div id="tablecontainer" style="display: none">
<table id="Other" style="display: none">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="txtOthers" type="text" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</div>
```

Remove the myFunction from text input

```
<input type="hidden" id="myInput" value="Business">
```

If you are using jquery, then use document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var fieldval = $("#myInput").val();
   if(fieldval == "Business"){
      $("#tablecontainer").css('display','block');
   }
   else{
      $("#tablecontainer").css('display','none');
   }
});
```

Also make sure you are getting value for the input field myInput from session.

Hope it works.